# AIX - BASH REGEX INTO IF STATEMENTS = Segmentation fault (coredump)

Tags: bash, regular-expression, aix

Hello everyone and thanks for your support!

I'm facing a problem while using REGEX inside a bash script through =~ operand.

Environment:
GNU bash, version 4.1.7(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix5.1.0.0)

```
bash-4.1$ if [[ a =~ a ]]; then echo match; fi
Segmentation fault(coredump)
```

The bash version:

```
bash-4.1$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.7(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix5.1.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

I'm looking for the best way to identify if a given argument is an integer because I need to be sure the given argument is a **PID (process id)**
In Linux i always use =~

I have not been able to find solutions. I've searched online but can't find anything similar.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How did you test bash version?

Comment: I just did this:

bash-4.1$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.7(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix5.1.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
bash-4.1$

Comment: Please add this to the question @omar.c.

Comment: I'm looking for the best way to identify if a given argument is an integer because I need to be sure the given argument is a **PID (process id)**

Comment: Does your bash support `shopt -s extglob`? Something like `[[ $n = +([0-9]) ]]` might be possible with it.

Comment: @omar.c you don't need regex support for that. So, is the question "how can I check if a variable contains nothing but numbers?", or is it "how can I check if this is a real, existing PID?" or maybe "how can I check if this could be a PID, even if the PID's process no longer exists?" or is it "why is my bash crashing on this simple test"? Can you please [edit] your question and clarify what, exactly, you are asking?

Comment: Does `[[ $pid == *[!0-9]* ]]` work as a test for non-numerics for you?

Comment: Does it also need to be a valid **current** pid? You might as well just ask `ps -p "${a}" &> /dev/null` and test exit status `${?}`.

Comment: Exactly what is the value of `a` which causes this issue? It being treated as a string on the left and a Bash pattern on the right.

Comment: I put a (corrected) version of my 3 tips in an answer, I hope one works for you (and it may help others as well. The "firt column starts with a space sometimes, other times not, depending on it's content size" bit me a few time before). I'll delete the above comments

Comment: @terdon sorry, I suppose I put too many things in a question.
My goal is the best way to check if is a pid, but I also would know related things such as: Does =~ works in AIX bash? Is segmentation fault abnormal? 
Sorry for my bad exposing, i was looking around the whole context

Comment: @omar.c Install some other version of bash, segfault is not acceptable behaviour. As a start, check your AIX-version: `oslevel -r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I'd use other means than bash-testing $pid.

I'd use `kill` or `awk` instead:

1 - to just check if $pid is a (valid, running) process on AIX:

```
kill -s 0 -- "$pid" && echo "pid $pid is a running process"
```

Note: this will NOT kill the process, signal 0 just works if the $pid exist.

**However** (thanks to @ChrisDavies for pointing it out in the comments!) : "... you must be the owner of the process (or root) to avoid getting an Operation not permitted error"

2 - if you are unsure wheter you got the correct column (This happens a lot with ps output, as the first column (USER) can start with a space or not depending on the username's length):

you probably need to add a space BEFORE the input line:

```
ps ... | sed -e 's/^/ /' | awk -v pid="$pid" ' something on column $pid '
```

: this will help awk (and sort and everything else) to not mitakenly see some pid in the first or second column ($1 or $2) depending if the content of that "first" column started with a space or not.

3 - To avoid the problem altogether you could also use a custom ps : You still need the sed as shorter pid's will start with a space, and the longest ones will not!

```
ps -e -o 'pid, ppid, user, etime, args' \
| sed -e 's/^/ /' \
| awk '
  BEGIN {
      col_pid=1;  col_ppid=2; col_user=3; col_etime=4 start_args=5 
  }
  
  ( $col_pid !~ "/^[0-9]+$/ ) {
      print "line: " FNR " : column " col_pid " does NOT match a number? : \047" $col_pid "\047" 
  }
  '
# you could also do the sed part with awk, but it would : recompute $0, losing spacings
```

Comment: "_signal 0 just works if the $pid exist_" - and you must be the owner of the process (or root) to avoid getting an `Operation not permitted` error

Comment: Oh, very important precision indeed, thanks  @ChrisDavies !

Comment: You need a `case` statement to sort it out properly. For example, `pid=28306; st=$(LANG=C kill -0 "$pid" 2>&1); ss=$?; case "$ss-$st" in 0-*) echo "Exists and is mine" ;; 1-*permitted) echo "PID $pid exists but not mine" ;; 1-*process) echo "PID $pid does not exist" ;; *) echo "Unsure about PID $pid: SS=$ss, ST=$st" ;; esac`

Comment: Why do you need the space? Awk doesn't care, it collapses consecutive field separators. Try `printf 'none\n one\n  two\n   three\n' | awk '{print ":"$1":"}'`. And when could you have a PID that isn't numerical? There's no point in testing the `ps` output, the OP needed to test a variable to see if _it_ could be a PID. Anything listed as a PID by `ps` will be a PID by definition, right?

Comment: @terdon The header line needs to be dealt with, via `NR>1` or `! /PID/`. There is always the possibility of race conditions with short-lived processes.

Comment: @terdon: I do need it on some old aix(&awk), I noticed that adding the space solved it for me. I didn't dig much further but each time I had the pb it was because the 1st column had the 1st line (header usually) starting at beginning of line and some of its values (ex: usernames, or pid, or ...) sometimes had space padding on the left : those appeared in $2.

Comment: (or when 1st col in TITLE had padding and some of its values do not, ex: PID)

Comment: @terdon : I found back when it posed a pb: `printf 'none\n one\n  two\n   three\n' | awk -F ' +' '{print ":"$1":"}'` # sees "none" and if print $2 we see the others. Why does it treat the default FS differently?  (even though it does help the general use case ^^): `awk '{BEGIN print "\047" FS "\047" }' | tr ' ' '%'` # does show there is just " " (=1 space) in the default FS? it should show `   three` several columns further? ( when I put a : `tr ' ' '/'` before the awk, and change its invocation to `awk -F'/' ...` it acts like I expect.   But with `" "` as FS, it acts differently

Comment: (FWIW: I sometimes need to specify the FS. for exemple some commands will put "at least 2 spaces" between fields as some columns may contain space, so I need to use: " {2,}" as FS. `echo "a    b    c d   e   f g" | awk -F' {2,}' '{print NF}' # outputs 5, as expected` . When using `" {2,}"` as FS, I also need to add at least 2 spaces at the beginning in the general case, depending on the content of the first col (which for some lines can have >=2 left-padding spaces, and 0<=nb_of_padding_space<2 for others).

Comment: Ah yes, but that is because you are using a regex, so you are explicitly telling awk to do this. It isn't needed if you don't use a regex.